# How to filter options by data-attribute with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have a select box with various options:

```
<select id="person">
  <option data-project_ids=​"11 23 19" value=​"17">​Goodwin, Alisha​</option>​
  <option data-project_ids=​"16" value=​"20">​Ratke, Danny​</option>​
  <option data-project_ids=​"" value=​"16">​Powlowski, Ron​</option>​
  <option data-project_ids=​"19 7" value=​"20">​Ratke, Danny​</option>​
</select>
```

How can I filter the options by a `data-project_id`?

Right now I have:

```
var project = 19; // just an example
$('#person').html().filter('[data-project_ids="' + project + '"]');
```

This *would* work if every option had only *one* `data-project_id`. However, there are often many, sometimes none at all.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check my answer out, it is the exact thing you need.

Comment: As a sidenote, data attributes do in fact support strings that looks like arrays, and they will be parsed as such by jQuery, which would it so much easier to just use $.inArray on the data attribute in a filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest reformatting your space separated string values to array syntax. jQuery.data will automatically read as array

A big advantage to this over the using `contains` selectors is precision. You will only get return when values are identical, `contains` selectors will return partial matches also.

```
<option data-project_ids=​"[11,23,19]" value=​"17">​Goodwin, Alisha​</option>
```

Then filter can be like:

```
var project = 19
$('#person option').filter(function(){
   return $.inArray(project, $(this).data('project_ids')) > -1
});
```

Will be easy to add or remove ID's using conventional array methods (push, splice etc)

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b6yuw/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks @adeneo ...also just dawned on me will only get absolute matches, whereas `contains` will return partial matches as well

Comment: @charlietfl: Absolute matches is perfect for me in this case. Still playing with your code. Already learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 6):

if you do:

```
$("#person [data-project_ids*=19]")
```

it would even select `data-project_ids=192`, but you can do this instead:

```
$("#person [data-project_ids~=19]")
```

`~=` is jQuery's [attribute-contains-word selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.

Comment: @Mehran Hatami: Thanks for your help. The second one does pretty much what I need. I am still testing it though.

Comment: but what if ID `191` exists? Will match that also. `contains` selectors are not always precise enough

Comment: @charlietfl: `what if ID 191 exists?`, ok then, if you want to select the exact nodes with the ID 191, you should do `$("#person [data-project_ids~=191]")` and if you want all the nodes with ID `19` in it, like `319 or 191 or 219`, you can do `$("#person [data-project_ids*=19]")`

Comment: @MehranHatami I rather doubt OP wants partial matches. If `19` exists, and `319` but filter is wanting `19` , will get both using a `contains` approach. I'm just pointing out a limitiation to the approach.

Comment: @charlietfl: you're right, but the answer covers the both approaches. ...Cheers! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#person [data-project_ids*=19]")` should work.

Comment: No, because some of the elements have attribute values like "12 15 19".

Comment: Fair enough, I've updated my comment. However, I feel the OP is likely solving whatever problem he is having the wrong way in the first place.

Comment: Agreed - it's not the best way to organize those values.

Comment: it would even select `data-project_ids=192`, check my answer out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What do you guys think would be a better way to "organize" those values?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, overall?